# Как добавить в C# проект dll, написанный на C++?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, lib

Имеется библиотека dll. К ней так же имеется файлы lib, def и заголовочный h.
Как подключить всё это добро к C# проекту?

Comment: InterOp https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x8kf7zx.aspx Pinvoke http://pinvoke.net/

Comment: Насколько я понял, это как в С++ вызывать dll, сделанную в C#. А мне надо наоборот.

Comment: Именно  вызов нативной DLL из манагед кода https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Вот еще https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/55d3thsc.aspx